# Namecheap webmail and amazon ec2

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, mailchimp, sendgrid, mandrill

I'm trying to setup incoming email for my Amazon EC2 linux box. It's a nightmare to figure out honestly, so I was looking into easier options (Amazon SES is not available in my region..)

My domain's DNS is managed through NameCheap. They have a private email hosting service.

https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/email.aspx

Will this enable me to have a webmail interface where I can send / receive emails from my domain?

And will I then be able to use a service like Mandril / Mailchimp / Sendgrid to deliver email from my Node.js application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is `YES`.

With current aws services, mail server is not that easier you can work it out in aws ec2 instance or SES service. I tried, but that's not happy story, especially you need put effords to maintain security and blacklist.

The AWS WorkMail services is bit expensive if compare with other web hosting.

So you should be confident to use webmail services provided by other hosting companies, and there are a lot of choices, enjoy it.